# Mysql show only the messages in between dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have my mysql database table messages is like this

```
id   message    start_date    end_date
1    message1   2013-09-29    2013-11-30
2    message2   2013-08-20    2013-09-30
3    message3   2013-06-20    2014-01-01
4    message4   2013-06-06    2013-09-20
5    message5   2013-10-25    2014-03-05
```

I want to show the message when the `start_date is equal to today and today is greater than start_date` and also in the same way it should show the message ``before end_date. Once the end_date has been crossed then it should not show the messages. For that I have done like this

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE start_date >= CURDATE( )  and end_date >= CURDATE( );
```

But this one is showing all the messages whose start date has not come. Like the row `5th(5    message5   2013-10-25    2014-03-05)`. So I want only the messages in between the start_date is today and start_date has been crossed and it will show until end_date. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Given your example data, do you only want one row returned (id=1)?

Comment: No I want more then one rows within that dates range..

Comment: Then given the data in your example, please show which rows you want returned.  Your comment says you want rows where `start_date is equal to today` but your code shows "greater than or equal to today".  In other words, it's not clear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

**Edit:**

<del>SELECT * FROM messages WHERE NOW() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;</del>

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

FYI, in your original query you only have to change the direction of the operator when comparing start_date :

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE start_date <= CURDATE() and end_date >= CURDATE();
```

Comment: Beware that your first example includes the whole of `start_date` but only exactly midnight on `end_date`.  This is not usually what one wants.  Using `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()` will fix it.